# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The ALLOWED_HOSTS setting must be a list or a tuple after upgrading Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Hi I upgrade the django and after that I'm getting this error `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The ALLOWED_HOSTS setting must be a list or a tuple.`
but in my setting.py file the ALLOWED_HOSTS is already in the list

config.py

```
DJANGO_CONFIG = {
'secret_key': 'fadfas-------',
'debug': False,
'admin_module': True,
'allowed_hosts': '[\'*\']',
'server_host': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
}
```

setting.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = DJANGO_CONFIG['allowed_hosts']
```

Comment: '[\'*\']' is a string, not a list

Comment: okay the error is gone but now it is not running mean if i run `python manage.py runserver --insecure` or `python manage.py runserver` it does not show any output

Comment: I change 'allowed_hosts': '[\'*\']' to 'allowed_hosts': []

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow any particular ip you can add it as shown below.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']
```

And if want to allow all, add it as shown below

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have even `ALLOWED_HOSTS = [*]` in DJANGO_CONFIG and try to extract it, you extract string, not list. You should write some like this in settings.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = list(DJANGO_CONFIG['allowed_hosts'])
```

Answer (score 0):

sttings.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [DJANGO_CONFIG['allowed_hosts']]
```

config.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = '*',
```